# Set string as current date

Tags: c++, date, time-t

I need to write files with the current date included in the name.
Currently this is what I have tried:

```
    time_t t = time(0);
    struct tm * now = localtime(&t);
    string date=now->tm_mday+'/'+(now->tm_mon+1)+'/'+(now->tm_year+1900);
```

Preferably I'd like to keep this method of getting the date as I have used it earlier on in my program.

Comment: And the problem with that is?

Comment: Use [`std::ostringstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostringstream). `+` doesn't work like you think it does.

Comment: @BenjaminBannier i tried printing it and its just an E symbol

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ yeah I got that, the point is it doesn't work

Comment: @CameronLyall What _doesn't_ work in particular? The usage is pretty straightforward.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ when i print the string it gives a weird symbol. Not the date

Comment: Post a [MCVE] of what you're doing in your question please.

Comment: `+` doesn't work like you think it does.  `int+char+int+char+int` does not produce a concatenated string of characters.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would use `std::put_time`, something like this:

```
time_t t = time(0);
struct tm * now = localtime(&t);

your_file << std::put_time(now, "%d/%m/%Y");
```

If you mean that you need to include the date in the name of a new file, then write to a stringstream, and use `your_stream.str()` to get a string containing the value.

If (though it strikes me as unlikely) you find that imposes excessive overhead, you could use `strftime` instead. It writes a date/time directly to a C-style string:

```
char buffer[64];

strftime(buffer, sizeof(buffer), "%d/%m/%Y", now);
```

Comment: Sorry, I realise i wasn't very clear. What I'm actually trying to do is write the file name with the date in it. For this I need to be able to have it as a String.

Answer (score 2):

I have often used [std::strftime](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/c/strftime) a bit like this:

```
// use strftime to format time_t into a "date time"
std::string get_date(std::time_t timer)
{
    char buf[sizeof("02/05/2015")]; // big enough for 02/05/2015\0
    std::tm tp = *std::localtime(&timer); // not thread safe
    return {buf, std::strftime(buf, sizeof(buf), "%d/%m/%Y", &tp)};
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << get_date(std::time(0)) << '\n';
}
```

**Output:**

```
02/05/2016
```